# How to strip all the code from a string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, web-scraping

I have the following html page saved in a variable after scrapping a website:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" > <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"> <head> <!-- HTTP 1.1 --> <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store"/> <!-- HTTP 1.0 --> <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/> <!-- Prevents caching at the Proxy Server llllll --> <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> <meta name="author" content="Ministerul Finantelor Publice"/> <link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon.ico"/> <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/> <script type="text/javascript"><!-- var nVer = navigator.appVersion; var nAgt = navigator.userAgent; var browserName = navigator.appName; var fullVersion = ''+parseFloat(navigator.appVersion); var majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion,10); var nameOffset,verOffset,ix; // In MSIE, the true version is after "MSIE" in userAgent if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("MSIE"))!=-1) { browserName = "Microsoft Internet Explorer"; fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+5); } // In Opera, the true version is after "Opera" else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Opera"))!=-1) { browserName = "Opera"; fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+7); } // In Chrome, the true version is after "Chrome" else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Chrome"))!=-1) { browserName = "Chrome"; fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+9); } // In Safari, the true version is after "Safari" //else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Safari"))!=-1) { //browserName = "Safari"; // fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8); //} // In most other browsers, "name/version" is at the end of userAgent else if ( (nameOffset=nAgt.lastIndexOf(' ')+1) < (verOffset=nAgt.lastIndexOf('/')) ) { document.write('<'+'link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/styles/andreas01/themeDefault.css" />'); } else{ document.write('<'+'link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/styles/andreas01/themeDefault.css" />'); } // trim the fullVersion string at semicolon/space if present if ((ix=fullVersion.indexOf(";"))!=-1) fullVersion=fullVersion.substring(0,ix); if ((ix=fullVersion.indexOf(" "))!=-1) fullVersion=fullVersion.substring(0,ix); majorVersion = parseInt(''+fullVersion,10); if (isNaN(majorVersion)) { fullVersion = ''+parseFloat(navigator.appVersion); majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion,10); } document.write('<'+'link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/styles/andreas01/theme'+browserName+majorVersion+'.css" />'); --></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="/styles/andreas01/print.css" /> <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/prototype.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/scriptaculous.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/global.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> var _gaq = _gaq || []; _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-2298641-2']); _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']); _gaq.push(['_trackPageLoadTime']); (function() { var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true; ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'; var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s); })(); </script> <title></title> <meta name="description" content=""/> <meta name="keywords" content=""/> </head> <body style="background-color:#ffffff"> <div id="page" > <div id="header" class="clearfix"> <form name="licitatiiForm" method="post" action="/acasa.html"> <input type="hidden" name="pagina" value="cauta"> <!DOCTYPE html> <script type="text/javascript"> var min=8; var max=18; function increaseFontSize() { var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p'); for(i=0;i<p.length;i++) { if(p[i].style.fontSize) { var s = parseInt(p[i].style.fontSize.replace("px","")); } else { var s = 12; } if(s!=max) { s += 1; } p[i].style.fontSize = s+"px" } } function decreaseFontSize() { var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p'); for(i=0;i<p.length;i++) { if(p[i].style.fontSize) { var s = parseInt(p[i].style.fontSize.replace("px","")); } else { var s = 12; } if(s!=min) { s -= 1; } p[i].style.fontSize = s+"px" } } </script> <img style="position:relative;margin-left:0px auto; margin-right: 0px auto; top:20px; float:left;" height="130" width="987" src="/styles/andreas01/images/banner.jpg" usemap="#home" /> <map name="home"> <area shape="circle" coords="70,61,49" alt="Acasa" href="/acasa.html?method=inceput&pagina=acasa" /> <!--<area shape="rect" coords="650,80,850,120" style="border-color: red" alt="Eveniment" href="/event.html" />--> </map> <div id="event"> </div>  <!--<div id="cauta"><a href="/harta.html">Hart&#259;</a></div>--> <div id="cauta"> |<a href="/harta.html">Hart&#259; site</a> |C&#259;utare <input type="text" name="cauta" value="" style="width:70px ;height:10px"> <a href="javascript:decreaseFontSize();"> <span style="text-decoration: none"><img src="/images/a_mic.gif"/></span></a> <a href="javascript:increaseFontSize();"> <span style="text-decoration: none"><img src="/images/A.gif"/></span></a><br>   <br>    <br><br><br> <span style="text-decoration: none">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span> <a href="http://www.facebook.com/mfpromania" target="_blank"> <img src="/images/facebook.png"/></a>   <a href="https://twitter.com/ro_mfp" target="_blank"> <img src="/images/twitter.png"/></a> </div> </form> </div> <div id="desp" align="center"> <div id="vista_toolbar"> <ul> <li><a class="acasa2" href="/acasa.html?method=inceput&pagina=acasa">&nbsp;Acas&#259;&nbsp;</a></li> <li><a href="/echipa.html?pagina=domenii">Domenii de activitate</a></li> <li><a href="/ueprezentare.html?&pagina=ue">Afaceri Europene</a></li> <li><a href="/prezentare.html?&pagina=stabilitate">Stabilitate financiar&#259;</a></li> <li><a href="/execbug.html?pagina=buletin">Buletin MFP</a></li> <li><a class="contact2" href="/acasa.html?method=comunicate&pagina=presa&locale=ro">Presa</a></li> </ul> </div> </div> <div id="content" class="clearfix">&nbsp; <br /> <font size="0.8em"> </font> <div > <table align="right" > <tr> <td> <div id="sub_acasa"> <a href ="http://www.transparenta-bugetara.gov.ro/" target="_blank"> <img src="/images/TRANSPARENTA.jpg"></a> </div></td></tr> <tr> <td> <div id="sub_acasa"> <img src="/styles/andreas01/images/interes.jpg" > <br> <a href ="/prioritatistrategice.html?pagina=prioritatistrategice">Priorit&#259;&#539;i strategice &#537;i planuri de ac&#539;iuni ale MFP </a> <br><hr /> <a href ="/programDeConvergenta.html?pagina=programConvergenta">Program de convergen&#355;&#259; </a> <br><hr /> <a href ="/pachete.html?pagina=pachete" >Pachet finan&#355;are extern&#259; </a> <br> <hr /> <a href ="/certificateemisiigaze.html?pagina=certificateemisiigaze" >Certificate de emisii gaze cu efect de ser&#259; </a> <br> <hr /> <img src="/images/engl.jpg">&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href ="/trezorengl.html?pagina=domenii" >Treasury and Public <br>Debt </a> <br> <hr /> <img src="/images/rom.jpg">&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href ="/rapoarteMFP.html?pagina=domenii" >Trezorerie &#351;i datorie <br>public&#259; </a> <hr /> <a href ="/noutatiLegislative.html?pagina=domenii" >Nout&#259;&#355;i legislative </a> <hr /> <a href ="/pdfbuget.html?pagina=acasa" >Bugetul MFP </a> <hr /> <a href ="reformabugue.html?pagina=domenii" >Bugetul UE </a> <br> <hr /> <a href ="/sec.html?pagina=acasa" >Certificat atestare SEC </a> <br> </a> <br> </div> </td></tr> <!-- <tr> <td> <div id="sub_acasa"> <a href ="/oportunitatiangajare.html?pagina=acasa"> <img src="/images/oprtunitatiangajare.jpg"></a> </div></td></tr> --> <tr> <td> <div id="sub_acasa"> <a href ="/publicatiipresa.html?pagina=presa"> <img src="/images/revista.jpg"></a> </div></td></tr> <tr> <td> <div id="sub_acasa"> <a href ="/ghiduriilustrate.html?pagina=acasa"> <img src="/images/ghiduriulustrate.jpg"></a> </div></td></tr> <tr> <td> <!-- <div id="sub_acasa"> <a href ="/prezentari2016.html?pagina=acasa"> <img src="/images/prezentari.jpg"></a> </div></td></tr> <tr> <td> <div id="sub_acasa"> <a href ="/loteriabonurilor.html?pagina=loteriabonurilor"> <img src="/images/loteriabonurilor.jpg"></a> </div></td></tr>--> <tr> <td> <div id="sub_acasa"> <a href ="/telverde.html?pagina=telverde"> <img src="/images/telverde.jpg"></a> </div></td></tr> <tr> <td> <div id="sub_acasa"> <img src="/styles/andreas01/images/agenti.jpg"> <br> <a href ="/ghidajstat.html?pagina=domenii"> Ajutor de stat </a> <br><hr /> <a href ="/publicitateinselatoareForm.html?pagina=acasa"> Publicitate &#206;n&#351;el&#259;toare </a> <br><hr /> <a href ="/datoriaguv.html?pagina=domenii"> Ghidul investitorului </a> <br><hr /> <a href ="/infotva.html?pagina=infotva">Info TVA </a> <br><hr /> <a href ="http://www.anaf.ro/SolDecont/" target="_blank">Verificare online rambursare TVA </a> <br><hr /> <a href ="/pjuridice.html?pagina=domenii">Informa&#355;ii fiscale &#351;i bilan&#355;uri </a> <br><hr /><!-- <a href ="/obiee.html?pagina=domenii">Indicatori economico-financiari </a> <br><hr />--> <a href="http://www.anaf.ro/anaf/internet/ANAF/asistenta_contribuabili/programe_utile" target="_blank">ANAF-Programe utile (Declara&#355;ii - ghi&#351;eu , fi&#351;e fiscale, Ordine de plat&#259;, Centralizator autovehicule in leasing)</a> <br> <hr /> <a href ="http://www.anaf.ro/anaf/internet/ANAF/servicii_online/declaratii_electronice/informatii_depunere_decl_juridice" target="_blank">Informa&#355;ii depunere declara&#355;ii electronice </a> <br><br> </div> </td></tr> <tr> <td> <div id="sub_acasa"> <img src="/styles/andreas01/images/institutii.jpg"> <br> <hr /> <a href ="/legismanag.html?pagina=domenii">Control intern/managerial &#351;i control financiar preventiv </a> <br><hr /> <a href ="/strategiaucaapi.html?pagina=domenii">Unitatea Central&#259; de Armonizare pentru Auditul Public Intern </a> <br><hr /> <a href ="/scrisoare.html?pagina=domenii">Scrisoare cadru pentru bugetul anului urm&#259;tor </a> <br><hr /> <a href ="/rapoarteMFP.html?pagina=domenii#tabs-2">&#206;mprumuturi locale <br><br> </a> </div> </td></tr> <tr> <td><div id="sub_acasa"> <img src="/styles/andreas01/images/fizice.jpg"> <br> <a target="_blank" href ="http://discutii.mfinante.ro/static/10/Mfp/MRDG_ro_fin.pdf">Ghid pentru restructurarea extrajudiciar&#259; a împrumuturilor cu garan&#355;ii ipotecare </a> <br><hr /> <a href ="/despagubForm.html?pagina=acasa" target="_parent">Verificare desp&#259;gubiri ANRP </a> <br><hr /> <a href ="https://www.anaf.ro/anaf/internet/ANAF/servicii_online/declaratii_electronice/Inf_depunere_persoane_fizice" target="_blank">Informa&#355;ii depunere declara&#355;ii electronice </a> <br><hr /> <a href ="https://www.anaf.ro/anaf/internet/ANAF/asistenta_contribuabili/persoane_fizice/despre_impozite_si_taxe/Despre_impozitul_pe_venit" target="_blank">Impozitul pe venit </a> <!-- <br><hr /> <a href =" https://www.anaf.ro/asistpublic/?tip=mfp" target="_blank">Formular de contact MFP/ANAF </a>--><br> <br> </div> </td></tr> <tr> <td> </td></tr></table> </div> <div id="nav"> <div class="wrapper"> <h2 class="accessibility">Navigation</h2> <ul id="primary-nav" class="menuList"> <li class="menubar"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Prezentare" style="width: 120px">Prezentare</a> <ul> <li> <a href="/rol.html?pagina=acasa" title="Rolul &#351;i organizarea MFP" >Rolul &#351;i organizarea MFP</a> </li> <li> <a href="/istoricul.html?pagina=acasa" title="Istoric MFP" >Istoric MFP</a> </li> <li> <a href="/conducere.html?pagina=acasa" title="Conducere" >Conducere</a> </li> <li class="last"> <a href="/declaratii.html?pagina=acasa" title="Declara&#355;ii avere &#351;i interese" >Declara&#355;ii avere &#351;i interese</a> </li> </ul> </li> <li> <a href="/acasa.html?method=agenda&categorie=AgendaMinistru&pagina=acasa" title="Agenda public&#259;" >Agenda public&#259;</a> </li> <li class="menubar"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Informa&#355;ii publice " style="width: 120px">Informa&#355;ii publice </a> <ul> <li> <a href="/planinstit.html?pagina=acasa" title="Programe &#351;i strategii" >Programe &#351;i strategii</a> </li> <li> <a href="/pdfbuget.html?pagina=acasa" title="Buget &#351;i contabilitate intern&#259;" >Buget &#351;i contabilitate intern&#259;</a> </li> <li> <a href="organigr.html?pagina=acasa" title="Organigrama" >Organigrama</a> </li> <li> <a href="rof_2009.html?pagina=acasa" title="ROF" >ROF</a> </li> <li> <a href="/proceduri.html?pagina=acasa" title="Proceduri" >Proceduri</a> </li> <li> <a href="/listadocumente.html?pagina=acasa" title="Lista documentelor" >Lista documentelor</a> </li> <li> <a href="formularetip.html?pagina=acasa" title="Formulare tip" >Formulare tip</a> </li> <li class="last"> <a href="/alteinformatii.html?pagina=acasa" title="Alte informatii" >Alte informatii</a> </li> </ul> </li> <li> <a href="/acasa.html?method=licitatie&pagina=acasa" title="Achizi&#355;ii publice" >Achizi&#355;ii publice</a> </li> <li class="menubar"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Transparen&#355;&#259; decizional&#259; " >Transparen&#355;&#259; decizional&#259; </a> <ul> <li> <a href="/transparent.html?method=transparenta&pagina=acasa&locale=ro" title="Proiecte acte normative" >Proiecte acte normative</a> </li> <li> <a href="/proiecteachizitii.html?&pagina=acasa" title="Proiecte achizi&#355;ii publice" >Proiecte achizi&#355;ii publice</a> </li> <li class="last"> <a href="/acteaprobate.html?&pagina=acasa" title="Acte normative aprobate" >Acte normative aprobate</a> </li> </ul> </li> <li> <a href="/integritate.html?pagina=acasa" title="Integritate" >Integritate</a> </li> <li class="menubar"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Cariera profesional&#259;" >Cariera profesional&#259;</a> <ul> <li> <a href="scoala_infiintare.html?pagina=scoala" title="&#350;coala de finan&#355;e" >&#350;coala de finan&#355;e</a> </li> <li> <a href="internship.html?pagina=acasa" title="Internship 2016" >Internship 2016</a> </li> <li class="last"> <a href="/acasa.html?method=concurs&pagina=acasa" title="Concursuri" >Concursuri</a> </li> </ul> </li> <li> <a href="/contacte.html?pagina=acasa" title="Contacte" >Contacte</a> </li> <li> <a href="/subordonate.html?pagina=acasa" title="Institu&#355;ii subordonate" >Institu&#355;ii subordonate</a> </li> <li> <a href="/linkuriutile.html?pagina=acasa" title="Leg&#259;turi utile" >Leg&#259;turi utile</a> </li> </ul> <br /> <div > <table > <tr><td> <div id="buton"> <a href ="http://www.anaf.ro" target="_blank"> <img src="/images/anaf.jpg" /></a> </div> </td></tr> <tr><td> <div id="buton"> <a href ="http://www.datoriepublica.mfinante.gov.ro/trezor/pagina.html?method=inceput&locale=ro" target="_blank"> <img src="/images/datpub.jpg" /></a> </div> </td></tr> <tr><td> <div id="buton"> <a href ="http://data.gov.ro/organization/mfp" target="_blank"> <img src="/images/datagov.jpg" /></a> </div> </td></tr> <tr><td> <div id="buton"> <a href ="https://extranet.anaf.mfinante.gov.ro/anaf/extranet/Aplicatii" target="_blank"> <img src="/images/buton_sistem_national_raportare.jpg" /></a> </div> </td></tr> <tr><td> <div id="buton"> <a href ="http://www.mfinante.ro/fidelis.html?pagina=acasa" target="_parent"> <img src="/images/fidelis.jpg" /></a> </div> </td></tr> <tr><td> <div id="buton"> <a href ="http://www.mfinante.ro/loteriabonurilor.html?pagina=loteriabonurilor" target="_parent"> <img src="/images/loteriabonurilor.jpg" /></a> </div> </td></tr> <tr><td> <div id="buton"> <a href ="http://www.mfinante.ro/internship.html?pagina=acasa" target="_parent"> <img src="/images/internship1.jpg" /></a> </div> </td></tr> <tr><td> <div id="buton"> <a href ="http://www.emabucharest.ro/" target="_blank"> <img src="/images/emabucharest.jpg" /></a> </div> </td></tr> <tr><td> <div id="buton"> <a href ="http://ec.europa.eu/solvit/site/index_ro.htm" target="_blank"> <img src="/images/solvit1.jpg" /></a> </div> </td></tr> <tr><td> <tr><td> <div id="buton"> <a href ="https://www.anaf.ro/anaf/internet/ANAF/info_ue/m1ss/informatii_inregistrare/!ut/p/a1/hY9LD4IwEIR_iweu7EojVm8VTUl93IjQiykJL4NASoW_LxpNNFGc206-ycyChBBkpboiU6aoK1Xeb-me_Knv-g51BBdkgcwRW8HneweRDEA0APhDDD_zlG1WyDx6CKg3GPyVHwH-9B9BjlXwNXkCIxMFyKys48e7EatiQjOQOkkTnWj7qgc7N6ZplxZa2Pe9rSqV2rq28Buf162B8A2D5hKEeJ6V3Y5Nbntx4bc!/dl5/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/" target="_blank"> <img src="/images/M1SS.jpg" alt='M1SS este o aplica&#355;ie care permite companiilor s&#259; se înregistreze, s&#259; depun&#259; declara&#355;ii &#537;i s&#259; pl&#259;teasc&#259; TVA datorat Statului Membru de Consum prin intermediul portalului web pus la dispozi&#355;ie de c&#259;tre Statul Membru de Identificare (de regul&#259; Statul Membru în care compania &#537;i-a stabilit activitatea economic&#259;). Simplificarea const&#259; în oportunitatea ca respectivele companii s&#259; nu se mai înregistreze în fiecare dintre statele în care datoreaz&#259; TVA, dar s&#259; beneficieze de servicii electronice prin intermediul Statului Membru de Identificare. De asemenea, companiile vor fi taxate la rata TVA aplicabil&#259; în Statul Membru de Consum.' title='M1SS este o aplica&#355;ie care permite companiilor s&#259; se înregistreze, s&#259; depun&#259; declara&&#355;ii &#537;i s&#259; pl&#259;teasc&#259; TVA datorat Statului Membru de Consum prin intermediul portalului web pus la dispozi&#355;ie de c&#259;tre Statul Membru de Identificare (de regul&#259; Statul Membru în care compania &#537;i-a stabilit activitatea economic&#259;). Simplificarea const&#259; în oportunitatea ca respectivele companii s&#259; nu se mai înregistreze în fiecare dintre statele în care datoreaz&#259; TVA, dar s&#259; beneficieze de servicii electronice prin intermediul Statului Membru de Identificare. De asemenea, companiile vor fi taxate la rata TVA aplicabil&#259; în Statul Membru de Consum.' border="0" /></a> </div> </td></tr> <tr><td> <div id="buton"> <a href ="http://chat.anaf.ro/cod_tva.nsf/solicitare_tva" target="_blank"> <img src="/images/VIES_SOLICITARE.jpg"/></a></div> </td></tr> <tr><td><div id="buton"> <a href ="http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/customs/customs_duties/index_en.htm" target="_blank"> <img src="/images/SEED.jpg" /></a></div> </td></tr> <tr><td><div id="buton"> <a href ="http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/vatResponse.html" target="_blank"> <img src="/images/VIES_verificare.jpg" /></a></div> </td></tr> <tr><td><div id="buton"> <a href ="http://www.intrastat.ro/" target="_blank"> <img src="/images/intrastat.jpg" /></a></div></td></tr> <tr><td><div id="buton"> <a href ="http://www.swiss-contribution.ro/swiss" target="_blank"> <img src="/images/swiss1.jpg" /></a></div></td></tr> <!-- <tr><td><div id="buton"> <a href ="http://conaco.ro/" target="_blank"> <img src="/images/CONACO.jpg" /></a></div></td></tr> --> <table width="170" class="data" > <tr><td > Data ultimei actualiz&#259;ri:</td></tr> <tr><td > 20.08.2017</td></tr></table> <table width="170" class="data" > <tr><td > Structura &#351;i grafica au fost realizate cu mijloace proprii <a href=mailto:publicinfo@mfinante.ro>webmaster </a></td></tr> <tr><td > </td></tr></table> </table> </div> </div> </div> <div id="main"><br/> <font size="1" style="background-color: #f4f4f4; "> <a href=""></a>&raquo; </font> <br> <div align="center"><b>AGENTUL ECONOMIC CU CODUL UNIC DE IDENTIFICARE null</b></div> <br /> <div style="width: 50px;border: 1px solid ;border-color: #ddddff; margin-left: 10px"> <a href="/pjuridice.html" >Inapoi</a></div> <center><table bgcolor="white" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" > <tr> <td bgcolor="#9966cc" align="left" width="345"><font size="2" color="#ffffff" face="Times New Roman">Denumire platitor:</font></td> <td bgcolor="#9966cc" align="center" width="330"><font size="2" color="#ffffff" face="Times New Roman"> AMG - DIVIZIA DE SECURITATE SRL </font></td> </tr> <tr align="left"> <td width="345" bgcolor="#fcf8f5" ><font size="2" color="#0B0B0B" face="Times New Roman">Adresa:</font></td> <td align="center" width="330" bgcolor="#fcf8f5" ><font size="2" face="Times New Roman"> Str. SUCEVEI &nbsp;&nbsp;8A &nbsp;&nbsp;Bistriţa &nbsp;&nbsp; </font></td> </tr> <tr align="left"> <td width="345"><font size="2" color="#0B0B0B" face="Times New Roman">Judetul:</font></td> <td align="center" width="330"><font size="2" face="Times New Roman"> BISTRIŢA-NĂSĂUD </font></td> </tr> <tr align="left"> <td bgcolor="#fcf8f5" width="345"><font size="2" color="#0B0B0B" face="Times New Roman">Numar de inmatriculare la Registrul Comertului:</font></td> <td bgcolor="#fcf8f5" align="center" width="330"><font size="2" face="Times New Roman"> J06 /693 /2012 </font></td> </tr> <tr align="left"> <td width="345"><font size="2" color="#0B0B0B" face="Times New Roman">Act autorizare:</font></td> <td align="center" width="330"><font size="2" face="Times New Roman"> - </font></td> </tr> <tr align="left"> <td bgcolor="#fcf8f5" width="345"><font size="2" color="#0B0B0B" face="Times New Roman">Codul postal:</font></td> <td bgcolor="#fcf8f5" align="center" width="330"><font size="2" face="Times New Roman"> - </font></td> </tr> <tr align="left"> <td width="345"><font size="2" color="#0B0B0B" face="Times New Roman">Telefon:</font></td> <td align="center" width="330"><font size="2" face="Times New Roman"> 0755695901 </font></td> </tr> <tr align="left"> <td bgcolor="#fcf8f5" width="345"><font size="2" color="#0B0B0B" face="Times New Roman">Fax:</font></td> <td bgcolor="#fcf8f5" align="center" width="330"><font size="2" face="Times New Roman"> - </font></td> </tr> <tr align="left"> <td width="345"><font size="2" color="#0B0B0B" face="Times New Roman">Stare societate: </font></td> <td align="center" width="330"><font size="2" face="Times New Roman">INREGISTRAT din data 08 Noiembrie 2012</font></td> </tr> <tr align="left"> <td bgcolor="#fcf8f5" width="345"><font size="2" color="#0B0B0B" face="Times New Roman">Observatii privind societatea comerciala:</font></td> <td bgcolor="#fcf8f5" align="center" width="330">-</td> </tr> <tr align="left"> <td width="345"><font size="2" color="#0B0B0B" face="Times New Roman">Data inregistrarii ultimei declaratii: (*)</font></td> <td align="center" width="330"><font size="2" face="Times New Roman"> 22 Martie 2016 </font></td> </tr> <tr align="left"> <td bgcolor="#fcf8f5" width="345"><font size="2" color="#0B0B0B" face="Times New Roman">Data ultimei prelucrari: (**)</font></td> <td bgcolor="#fcf8f5" align="center" width="330"><font size="2" face="Times New Roman"> 22 Martie 2016 </font></td> </tr> <tr align="left"> <td width="345"><font size="2" color="#0B0B0B" face="Times New Roman">Impozit pe profit (data luarii in evidenta):</font></td> <td align="center" width="330"><font size="2" face="Times New Roman"> NU </font></td> </tr> <tr align="left"> <td bgcolor="#fcf8f5" width="345"><font size="2" color="#0B0B0B" face="Times New Roman">Impozit pe veniturile microintreprinderilor (data luarii in evidenta):</font></td> <td bgcolor="#fcf8f5" align="center" width="330"><font size="2" face="Times New Roman"> 01-01-2016 </font></td> </tr> <tr align="left"> <td width="345"><font size="2" color="#0B0B0B" face="Times New Roman">Accize (data luarii in evidenta):</font></td> <td align="center" width="330"><font size="2" face="Times New Roman"> NU </font></td> </tr>  <tr align="left"> <td bgcolor="#fcf8f5" width="345"><font size="2" color="#0B0B0B" face="Times New Roman">Taxa pe valoarea adaugata (data luarii in evidenta):</font></td> <td align="center" width="330"><font size="2" face="Times New Roman"> 12-11-2012 </font></td> </tr> <tr align="left"> <td width="345"><font size="2" color="#0B0B0B" face="Times New Roman">Contributia de asigurari sociale (data luarii in evidenta):</font></td> <td align="center" width="330"><font size="2" face="Times New Roman"> 01-01-2013 </font></td> </tr> <tr align="left"> <td bgcolor="#fcf8f5" width="345"><font size="2" color="#0B0B0B" face="Times New Roman">Contributia de asigurare pentru accidente de munca si boli profesionale datorate de angajator (data luarii in evidenta):</font></td> <td align="center" width="330"><font size="2" face="Times New Roman"> 01-01-2013 </font></td> </tr>   <tr align="left"> <td width="345"><font size="2" color="#0B0B0B" face="Times New Roman">Contributia de asigurari pentru somaj (data luarii in evidenta):</font></td> <td align="center" width="330"><font size="2" face="Times New Roman"> 01-01-2013 </font></td> </tr> <tr align="left"> <td bgcolor="#fcf8f5" width="345"><font size="2" color="#0B0B0B" face="Times New Roman">Contributia angajatorilor pentru Fondul de garantare pentru plata creantelor sociale (data luarii in evidenta):</font></td> <td align="center" width="330"><font size="2" face="Times New Roman"> 01-01-2013 </font></td> </tr> <tr align="left"> <td width="345"><font size="2" color="#0B0B0B" face="Times New Roman">Contributia pentru asigurari de sanatate (data luarii in evidenta):</font></td> <td align="center" width="330"><font size="2" face="Times New Roman"> 01-01-2013 </font></td> </tr>  <tr align="left"> <td bgcolor="#fcf8f5" width="345"><font size="2" color="#0B0B0B" face="Times New Roman">Contributii pentru concedii si indemnizatii de la persoane juridice sau fizice (data luarii in evidenta):</font></td> <td align="center" width="330"><font size="2" face="Times New Roman"> 01-01-2013 </font></td> </tr> <tr align="left"> <td width="345"><font size="2" color="#0B0B0B" face="Times New Roman">Taxa jocuri de noroc (data luarii in evidenta):</font></td> <td align="center" width="330"><font size="2" face="Times New Roman">NU</font></td> </tr> <tr align="left"> <td bgcolor="#fcf8f5" width="345"><font size="2" color="#0B0B0B" face="Times New Roman">Impozit pe veniturile din salarii si asimilate salariilor (data luarii in evidenta):</font></td> <td align="center" width="330"><font size="2" face="Times New Roman"> 01-01-2013 </font></td> </tr>    <tr align="left"> <td width="345"><font size="2" color="#0B0B0B" face="Times New Roman">Impozit pe constructii(data luarii in evidenta):</font></td> <td align="center" width="330"><font size="2" face="Times New Roman"> NU </font></td> </tr>    <tr align="left"> <td width="345"><font size="2" color="#0B0B0B" face="Times New Roman">Impozit la titeiul si la gazele naturale din productia interna (data luarii in evidenta):</font></td> <td align="center" width="330"><font size="2" face="Times New Roman"> NU </font></td> </tr> <tr align="left"> <td bgcolor="#fcf8f5" width="345"><font size="2" color="#0B0B0B" face="Times New Roman">Redevente miniere/Venituri din concesiuni si inchirieri (data luarii in evidenta):</font></td> <td align="center" width="330"><font size="2" face="Times New Roman"> NU </font></td> </tr>  <tr align="left"> <td width="345"><font size="2" color="#0B0B0B" face="Times New Roman">Redevente petroliere (data luarii in evidenta):</font></td> <td align="center" width="330"><font size="2" face="Times New Roman"> NU </font></div> </body> </html>
```

Now from here I want to extract a few fields like "Adresa", "Numar de inmatriculare la Registrul Comertului", more exactly their value.

I'm tired of trying. I tried to find an element, a div, anything that would specifically lead to those values, but there are none. I've tried to work with str_replace and replace all the words that I don't need like:

```
str_replace("<div", "", $htmlcode);
str_replace("</div", "", $htmlcode);
```

etc,, but it doesn't work. On some elements it does replace them, but on most it does nothing as if it couldn't replace them and yes I'm sure I typed correctly.

I tried strip_tags which doesnt work at all, it doesnt change the string

What can I do?

EDIT: This is not a duplicate, a simple look on other methods isn't going to solve it, I already read the post Lawrance pointed towards, I tried to make a DOMDOCUMENT as well and find elements that way, but it doesn't return anything, here:

```
$dom= new DOMDocument();
$dom ->loadHTML($htmlcode);
$dom ->validate();
$tds= $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');
foreach($tds as $node) {
  $dom->saveHTML($node);
}
```

The problem is that whatever method I'm trying to extract the infor appears to find nothing in the given string.